# Number of permutations that satisfy a given set of comparisons

Tags: co.combinatorics, sorting, permutations, topological-sorting

We are given a set of comparisons of the form `z[i] < z[j]` for various `i` and `j` and an unknown permutation `z` of length `n`.

We can assume those are transitively closed, or compute the closure relatively quickly by Floyd-Warshall.

Is there an efficient algorithm to determine the number of permutations compatible with the known comparisons? We can of course backtrack our way to the answer, but this would be quite slow.

The constraint we have looks like a forest of DAGs. It seems that by carefully counting the ways in which it can be collapsed into a line, we might get to the answer more directly.

Comment: As @a3nm mentions this is intractable for many comparisons, but there is likely a $poly(n) 2^{poly(k)}$ algorithm for $k$ comparisons, which would be much faster than brute force for small $k$.

Comment: I've also found out that simple Markov chain over the set of linear extensions can mix very quickly making it practical to sample for them. Given that I'm after the average number of inversions among extensions, this is perfect for me.

Comment: Although #P hard, it can be approximated (has a PTAS) via convex volume estimation.

Comment: I understand it involves 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your problem is equivalent to the following: given a partial order (represented by its comparability pairs, which forms a DAG), count how many linear extensions it has.

This problem is known to be #P-hard, see Brightwell and Winkler, "Counting Linear Extensions", Order, 1991. It is #P-hard even in quite restricted cases, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.06312

Comment: Perhaps it is useful to add that there are exceptions when considering restricted classes of partial orders. N-free posets (series-parallel partial orders) have a poly-time solution to count the number of linear extensions.